# How to access controller functions in karma test cases?

Tags: html, angularjs, karma-runner

I am new for angular and karma.

In angular i have one controller like below

```
angular.module('login').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.text = 'Hello World!';
    vm.text = 'hi';
});
```

And i write karma test case like below

```
    describe('LoginCtrl', function() {
           beforeEach(module('login'));
               beforeEach(module('auth2AdminUI'));
               var scope,ctrl,vm;

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
          scope = $rootScope.$new();
          ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {$scope: scope});
          vm = this.ctrl;
        }));

        it('Checck scope text', function () {
        expect(scope.text).toBe('Hello World!');
        });

        it('check vm text',function(){
           expect(vm.text).toBe('hi');
        })
```

Checck scope text test case was passed, but Checck vmtext was failed. i don't know why. Any problem with my code, I think i'm using **this** for accessing controller, this may problem.

Error:

```
  LoginCtrl
x check vm variable
  PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0)
  Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Tell me how can i access the variable and function of unsing this keyword in the controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Here vm is nothing but your controller it self so you can use Controller to test variables and functions.

```
describe('Login Ctrl Description', function () {
        var LoginCtrl;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            // Create Login controller
            LoginCtrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));
        it('check vm text', function () {
            expect(LoginCtrl.text).toBe('hi');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the controller context using `this` from outside of the controller. That's not possible. `this` is a JavaScript construct that allows to access the context from which a function was **called**. Since controllers are actually used as constructors `this` refers to the object that is constructed by angular using the `new` keyword (in other words, the controller is **called** as a constructor function) . So, `this` references the object that is built from the controller. This means that everything you add to `this` is a property of the new object. So, everything added to `this` is already public!

This is how I would do this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {$scope: scope});
      // vm = this.ctrl; //<--- This line is unnecessary, delete it
}));
```

Try this as a test then:

```
it('check vm text',function(){
       expect(ctrl.text).toBe('hi'); // Note that you should reference the controller since $controller constructs a new controller object and you store it in "ctrl"
})
```